# AnkhSVN got broken, it's absent from VS completely

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn

So my AnkhSVN got broken. It showed me some cryptic error message which I don't remember. And then it was no longer visible anywhere in VS (for example in context menus in the solution explorer).

I managed to fix it though. Will post answer.

Comment: Too bad you don't remember what the error was, I might have been able to tell you more. What probably happened is that the installer for VisualSvn ran devenv /setup and thereby fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to install VisualSVN then uninstall VisualSVN. Somehow this made AnkhSVN work again.